# Contains Returning False If Exist in List

Tags: c#

I'm running into a problem where the contains method is return false even though it exist in the list. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Program.CS

```
points.Add(new Point(-4, -7));
points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
points.Add(new Point(1, 2));
points.Add(new Point(-4, 5));
points.Insert(2, new Point(3, 1));
points.Add(new Point(7, -2));
points[0] = new Point(2, 1);
points.RemoveAt(2);

bool returnPoint = false;

returnPoint = points.Contains(new Point(1, 2));
```

PointList.CS

```
public bool Contains(Point item)
{
   return _Points.Contains(item);
}
```

Point.CS

```
public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }

public Point(int x, int y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

Comment: is `Point` a `struct` or a `class`?

Comment: If point is a reference type, `.Contains` is checking for referential equality. Since you're looking for a new object, the reference will never match.

Comment: @DanielA.White class

Comment: i would look up the difference between reference and value types.

Comment: Post an [MCVE]. You're leaving out way too much code. We can't even tell what type Point is.

Comment: It often makes more sense to model `Point` as an immutable struct.  The struct approach means you are saying, "it makes no sense to distinguish between two copies of Point(1,1), in the same way there is no way to distinguish between two copies of the number 5." With the class approach, you are saying, "It is possible to have distinct copies of Point(1,1)."  The latter approach works well for graphs. The former approach works well for graphics (and has [better performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2006/09/07/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming-solution/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Point` is a class, it is a reference type. By default, reference types check for referential equality. If you want to get the behavior you're expecting, you should override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `Point`, and it probably wouldn't hurt to implement `IEquatable<Point>` while you're at it, along with the `==` and `!=` operators.

An example implementation would look like this:

```
public class Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;

        return Equals((Point)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (X * 397) ^ Y;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Point left, Point right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Point left, Point right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

If that seems like a lot, well, it is. Unfortunately, implementing equality tends to require a good amount of boiler plate in C#. If we get Record types in C# 8 some of the pain may be alleviated, but until then this is the typical approach.

Comment: This is a good solution. I'll note that if you seal `Point` then you don't have to do a `GetType` check.

Answer (score 1):

Contains in `ArrayList` uses implementation of `Equals()` on the objects. Currently you are checking if object references are equal.

```
Point point = new Point(5, 2);
Point refPoint = point; // refer to same object
points.Add(point);

bool returnPoint = false;

returnPoint = points.Contains(refPoint); // return true
```

Need to override `Equals()` and `GetHashcode` in your class for reference types:

```
public override bool Equals(object other) {
 Point otherPoint = other as Point;

 if(otherPoint != null) 
    return (X.Equals(otherPoint.X) && (Y.Equals(otherPoint.Y)));

   return false;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but now would be a good time to note that if you're going to override `Equals`, it's probably a good idea to override `==` and `!=` and `GetHashCode` also.  Remember, you are *required* to ensure that if two objects are `Equals` true, then their hash codes are equal. You are *encouraged* to ensure that `==` and `Equals` have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Point is a reference type, so you're unintentionally comparing references, not properties.

You can compare properties by using LINQ's `Any()` and passing a lambda expression that performs the comparison you wish.

```
//using System.Linq;
returnPoint = points.Any( p => p.X == 1 && p.Y == 2 );
```

Comment: This approach is correct and does solve the OP's immediate problem, but still leaves the OP (and anyone else using the OP's code) vulnerable to similar errors elsewhere (and forces a similar correction elsewhere).  I recommend [Jonathan's Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656936/18192) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need valueObject for best practice solution and For comparison only x and y may not. you should think of functional processes as DDD design
[look here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html)

```
 public abstract class ValueObject
    {
        protected static bool EqualOperator(ValueObject left, ValueObject right)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) ^ ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return ReferenceEquals(left, null) || left.Equals(right);
        }

        protected static bool NotEqualOperator(ValueObject left, ValueObject right)
        {
            return !(EqualOperator(left, right));
        }
        protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues();

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }
            var other = (ValueObject)obj;
            var thisValues = GetAtomicValues().GetEnumerator();
            var otherValues = other.GetAtomicValues().GetEnumerator();
            while (thisValues.MoveNext() && otherValues.MoveNext())
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(thisValues.Current, null) ^ ReferenceEquals(otherValues.Current, null))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (thisValues.Current != null && !thisValues.Current.Equals(otherValues.Current))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return !thisValues.MoveNext() && !otherValues.MoveNext();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return GetAtomicValues()
               .Select(x => x != null ? x.GetHashCode() : 0)
               .Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
        }
    }
```

your PointList.cs

```
    public class PointList
{
    public string Bla { get; set; }

    public List<Point> Points { get; protected set; } = new List<Point>();

    public void AddPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        AddPoint(new Point(x, y));
    }
    public void AddPoint(Point p)
    {
        if (!Points.Any(x => x.Equals(p)))
            Points.Add(p);
    }
    public void RemovePoint(int x, int y)
    {
        RemovePoint(new Point(x, y));
    }
    public void RemovePoint(Point point)
    {
        Points.Remove(point);
    }
    public Point GetPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        return GetPoint(new Point(x, y));
    }
    public Point GetPoint(Point point)
    {
        return Points.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(point));
    }
}
```

your Point.cs

```
public class Point : ValueObject
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
        {
            yield return X;
            yield return Y;
        }
    }
```

Examples

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new PointList();
            list.AddPoint(1, 1);
            list.AddPoint(1, 2);
            list.AddPoint(14, 53);


            list.RemovePoint(1, 1);
            list.RemovePoint(new Point(1, 2));


            var p2 = list.GetPoint(14, 53);
            var p1 = list.GetPoint(new Point(14, 53));


        }
    }
```